# NodeJS Performance question - Single Threaded

Tags: node.js, single-threaded

Need some suggestions about how to handle operations in NodeJs. I have tried to search things but couldn’t find it anywhere, so I thought I will post it here to get the experts feedback.

We have built an E commerce platform using NextJS and NodeJS.

I still have to go test and do a load test confirming how do we perform, but I’m a little worried about all the statements and declarations about how nodejs is not a multi threading language and it is a show stopper and bla bla bla. So I am here to get your suggestion/feedback on what we are doing is okayish or not. This is what I have:

- Authentication Microservice: for authenticating requests and finding if the user has access to a particular module
- payment microservice: for accepting payments and refunds.
- Shopping Service
- MySQL and Sequelize

I will try to explain my question with an example of "order processing". So when I get a request to confirm an order, this is what I am doing to authenticate the request and confirm if details are full proof.

Confirm the request is authenticated through jwt token

Make a request to user auth and confirm user is a valid user and has access to order module.

Verify the price of items through database (because I’m assuming a payload can be hacked and wrong prices can be sent)

Verify if the discount is validated correctly from the database

Verify if the coupon is valid and the discount applied is correct or not

Check if the reward points sent are correct or not - a request to user service is sent

Our payment gateway is Razor Pay, here, we confirm if the payment id sent is a valid payment id, and the amount received from the user matches the total amount to be charged.

So this is a long list of validations we do at NodeJS right now.

It’s super fast on a single request. I will definitely tune things around when we go deep into load testing.... but my current dilemma right now is whether we have opted the right approach or not. Is NodeJS good enough to do this kind of execution. I am expecting no more than 200+ concurrent users in 6-7 months down the line so I am not toooooo worried about performance. I can do clustering and dockering to boost up performance. I want to know if I have made the right choice to do this in NodeJS. It’s not a very high cpu intensive algorithm, just some ‘for loops’ and some Database requests.

Should I keep this in Node, or should I move this code of algorithm in another service written in a different language like C++ or may be python.

Big time confused right now. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Node is single threaded but asynchronous and can handle many concurrent requests, you should be okay, and will be even faster with clustering should you implement it.

Comment: Great @mjrcodin, thanks for the help. Appreciate it ;) I will be posting my test results and benchmark testing soon so it can help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js may be single-threaded, but it should be fine with what you are doing.  It is well suited for horizontally scaling/clustering and there are plenty of node modules already there to help you out with that.

https://medium.com/iquii/good-practices-for-high-performance-and-scalable-node-js-applications-part-1-3-bb06b6204197

Additionally, Node.js is asynchronous and can handle concurrent requests.

I have also included an older link on how to scale node.js that lists how many users each scaling method can help support.  Long story short you can use vertical scaling, horizontal scaling, microservices(which it sounds like you already looking at) and automation to easily scale up your application.  Node.js should work fine.

https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-scale-a-nodejs-app-based-on-number-of-users/